# Does the "final"-modifier contradict the "@Lazy"-annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, modifier

When using the `@Lazy`-Annotation on a Spring-Bean, then the used beans should be lazy loaded.

When the bean however uses dependency injection through its constructor and the fields, which contain the used beans, are declared as `final`, then there should be no way for Spring to lazy load the dependencies.

I think this would happen even without the `final`-modifier, since the constructor has to be called when creating the bean (expect Spring uses reflection to lazy inject the used beans afterwards).

Is my assumption true?

Comment: Spring doesn't use reflection to lazy-inject the dependencies. It injects a proxy which can then be updated when the dependency has been initialized or when it is accessed the first time. This is another variation of the popular "Is Java pass-by-value or pass-by-reference" question

Comment: @knittl this comment sounds like an answer to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lazy dependencies/beans injected once at startup. They are not changed at runtime. Instead, a proxy class is used, which allows Spring to change or look up the actual bean at runtime. There is no need to circumvent `final`.

Let's look at an example. Given the following bean and consumer:

```
interface YourBean {
  boolean yourMethod();
}

@Component
class YourBeanImpl implements YourBean {
  @Override
  public boolean yourMethod() {
    return false;
  }
}

class YourConsumer {
  private final YourBean yourBean;
  public YourConsumer(@Lazy final YourBean yourBean) {
    this.yourBean = yourBean; // this will be an instance of `LazyYourBeanProxy`
  }

  public void doWork() {
    if (this.yourBean.yourMethod()) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

The proxy is generated dynamically, but it looks more or less equivalent to the following class:

```
class LazyYourBeanProxy implements YourBean {
  private final ApplicationContext appctx;

  public LazyYourBeanProxy(final ApplicationContext appctx) {
    this.appctx = appctx;
  }

  private YourBean getRealBean() {
    return this.appctx.getBean(YourBean.class);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean yourMethod() {
    return getRealBean().yourMethod();
  }
}
```

Now, anytime your consumer calls a method on the lazy bean, it goes first to the proxy implementation which can then (lazily; i.e. not at startup time, but at runtime) look up the bean in the application context and delegate the call to it.

The Spring Framework might employ additional cleverness like caching the real bean inside the proxy when it is looked up the first time, but this is the gist of it.

Comment: I tested it in debug mode aswell and it indeed works as described. It is also mention worthy, that Spring uses different Proxies for Classes (CGLIB) and Interfaces (JDK Dynamic Proxies).